# Passing modifiable arguments to Threads

Tags: python, multithreading, pointers

Hi I'm trying to track behavior of threads by having them modify a value eg:

```
def cam_Expose(camera, counter):
    camera.grab()
    counter= counter+ 1
    print('Confirm, this is the %d exposure!')
    
exposures = 0
while True:
    try:
        camera_worker = threading.Thread(
            target = cam_Expose,
            args = (camera, exposures),
        )
        camera_worker.start()
        camera_worker.join()
        print('This is the %d exposure!'% (exposures))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('User terminating collection')
        break
```

there are other threads operating in the background (a timed trigger to the camera) but they appear to be functioning as intended and are omitted here for clarity.

my output is:

> Confirm, this is the 1 exposure!
> This is the 0 exposure!
> Confirm, this is the 1 exposure!
> This is the 0 exposure!
> Confirm, this is the 1 exposure!
> This is the 0 exposure!
> ...
> User terminating collection.

the intended output is:

> Confirm, this is the 1 exposure!
> This is the 1 exposure!
> Confirm, this is the 2 exposure!
> This is the 2 exposure!
> Confirm, this is the 3 exposure!
> This is the 3 exposure!
> ...
> User terminating collection.

I've confirmed that the grab function is working as intended, the issue is that the thread is not modifying the values passed to it.

Comment: You could make the variable global and use locks

Comment: The code shown does not / will not produce that output. It will however run indefinitely

Comment: @jvx8ss Locks are only necessary for non-threadsafe objects. A global int (for example) would be threadsafe and therefore no locking required